# 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'badrequest' is returned when the bot is published on Teams channel.: Bot Framework

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, bots, azure-bot-service

I am a beginner learning the Bot framework in Azure.NET, I came across this bot sample (https://github.com/tompaana/intermediator-bot-sample) which perfectly demonstrates the human-hand off scenario. I could execute it on local host and it worked as expected.

When I published this POC on MS Teams channel through Azure Bot service, The code returns me the exception 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'badrequest'. This occurs particularly when '@Bot GetRequests' is typed in Teams. (This command is used to retrieve the pending accepted requests during human-hand off scenarios.)

Here is the code snippet which is causing the issue:

```
  //This is the Entry point method of the Bot application
  protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {

    if (turnContext.Activity.Text == "@Bot GetRequests")
    {
     await HandleCommandAsync(turnContext);
    }

 }

 public async virtual Task<bool> HandleCommandAsync(ITurnContext context)
 {
        Activity activity = context.Activity;           
        Command command = Command.FromMessageActivity(activity);          
        bool wasHandled = false;
        Activity replyActivity = null;
        ConversationReference sender = MessageRouter.CreateSenderConversationReference(activity);

        switch (command.BaseCommand)
        {               
            case Commands.GetRequests:

                IList<ConnectionRequest> connectionRequests = _messageRouter.RoutingDataManager.GetConnectionRequests();

                replyActivity = activity.CreateReply();

                replyActivity.Attachments = CreateMultipleConnectionRequestCards(_messageRouter,
                       connectionRequests, activity.Recipient?.Name);

                replyActivity.ChannelData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(connectionRequests);                                
                wasHandled = true;                  
                break;                             
       }

       if (replyActivity != null)
       {
            //Exception is thrown here when the Bot is published to Teams channel'
            await context.SendActivityAsync(replyActivity);
       }            
        return wasHandled;
   }


   public static IList<Attachment> CreateMultipleConnectionRequestCards(MessageRouter messageRouter,
        IList<ConnectionRequest> connectionRequests, string botName = null)
    {
        IList<Attachment> attachments = new List<Attachment>();

        foreach (ConnectionRequest connectionRequest in connectionRequests)
        {
            attachments.Add(CreateConnectionRequestCard(messageRouter, connectionRequest, botName).ToAttachment());
        }
        return attachments;
  }
```

I am just curious to know that if anyone in the developer community has ever been through the similar problem. If yes, I would really appreciate if I can get any help on this to come out of the issue.

Comment: When you say it works as expected when executing on localhost, do you mean you tested it in the Emulator or you connected your local bot to Teams using a tunneling service?

Comment: Hi @KyleDelaney, I have tested it in Emulator.

Comment: See if you can reproduce the Teams error while debugging the bot locally with [ngrok](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/10/19/debug-channel-locally-using-ngrok/). If you can, show us which line is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is in the below line of HandleCommandAsync(ITurnContext context) method.

```
replyActivity.ChannelData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(connectionRequests);
```

Just comment it and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error on teams, below is my code, on the emulator it shows nothing but on teams, it gives that operation returned an invalid bad request,

[image]

```
if (reasonintent == "Schedule")
                    {

                        //******************
                        UAT_LUIS_Entity UAT_LUIS = await GetEntityFromLUIS(turnContext.Activity.Text);
                        List<string> entityList = new List<string>();
                        String HourFromTime = "", HourToTime = "", MinToTime = "", MinFromTime = "", checkspecificdate = "";
                        String FromTime = "", ToTime = "", FromTimeHour = "", FromTimeMin = "", ToTimeHour = "", ToTimeMin = "";
                        for (int i = 0; i < UAT_LUIS.entities.Length; i++)
                        {
                            entityList.Add(UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower());
                            if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower() == "room")
                            {
                                roomluisname = UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower();
                            }

                            if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower() == "date")
                            {
                                dateluis = UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower();
                                checkspecificdate = "true"
                ;
                            }

                            if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower() == "today")
                            {
                                dateluis = UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower();
                            }

                            if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower() == "the day after tomorrow")
                            {
                                dateluis = UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower();
                            }
                            if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower() == "tomorrow")
                            {
                                dateluis = UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower();
                            }




                        }

                        String d = dateluis;


                        if (checkspecificdate == "true")
                        {
                            datevar = Convert.ToDateTime(dateluis);
                        }
                        else if (dateluis.Contains("today"))
                        {
                            datevar = DateTime.Today;
                        }
                        else if (dateluis.Contains( "tomorrow"))
                        {
                            datevar = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
                        }
                        else if (dateluis == "the day after tomorrow" || dateluis.Contains("day after tomorrow"))
                        {
                            datevar = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            datevar = DateTime.Today;
                        }


                        DateTime dateobject;
                        String datestring = "";
                        if (DateTime.TryParse(datevar.ToString(), out dateobject))
                        {

                            datestring = dateobject.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddT");

                        }




                        string datevarparticularstart = datestring + "00" + ":" + "00" + ":" + "01-08:00";
                        string datevarparticularend = datestring + "23" + ":" + "59" + ":" + "00-08:00";
                        var queryparticulardate = new List<QueryOption>()
                        {
                            new QueryOption("startDateTime", datevarparticularstart),
                            new QueryOption("endDateTime", datevarparticularend)
                        };

                        var calendarViewparticulardate = await graphClient.Me.CalendarView
                            .Request(queryparticulardate)
                            .GetAsync();
                        String luiscalenderentity = "";


                        //***********************





                        for (int i = 0; i < UAT_LUIS.entities.Length; i++)
                        {
                            entityList.Add(UAT_LUIS.entities[i].type.ToString().ToLower());
                            if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower().Contains("tulip"))
                            {
                                luiscalenderentity = "tulip";

                            }

                            else if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower().Contains("lotus"))
                            {
                                luiscalenderentity = "lotus";

                            }

                            else if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower().Contains("snowdrop"))
                            {
                                luiscalenderentity = "snowdrop";

                            }
                            else if (UAT_LUIS.entities[i].entity.ToString().ToLower().Contains("chanyaky"))
                            {
                                luiscalenderentity = "chanyaky";

                            }
                        }

                        string boolvarcheck = "";

                        if (calendarViewparticulardate.Count != 0)
                        {


                            for (int i = 0; i < calendarViewparticulardate.Count; i++)
                            {


                                if (calendarViewparticulardate[i].Location.DisplayName.ToLower().Contains(luiscalenderentity))
                                {
                                    boolvarcheck = "true";

                                    string converttostring1 = "";
                                    DateTime date1;
                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToDateTime(calendarViewparticulardate[i].Start.DateTime).AddHours(-8).ToString(), out date1))
                                    {

                                        converttostring1 = date1.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                                    }

                                    String vartime1 = converttostring1;

                                    // Convert.ToDateTime(calendarViewdate[0].End.DateTime).AddHours(-8);
                                    string converttostring2 = "";
                                    DateTime date2;
                                    if (DateTime.TryParse(Convert.ToDateTime(calendarViewparticulardate[i].End.DateTime).AddHours(-8).ToString(), out date2))
                                    {

                                        converttostring2 = date2.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
                                    }

                                    String vartime2 = converttostring2;


                                    EventNameschedule.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                    {
                                        Text = calendarViewparticulardate[i].Location.DisplayName,
                                        Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Small,
                                        Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Accent
                                    });
                                    Eventschedulestart.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                    {
                                        Text = vartime1,
                                        Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Small,
                                        Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Accent
                                    });
                                    Eventscheduleend.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                    {
                                        Text = vartime2,
                                        Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Small,
                                        Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Accent
                                    });
                                    Eventschedulesubject.Add(new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                    {
                                        Text = calendarViewparticulardate[i].Subject,
                                        Size = AdaptiveTextSize.Small,
                                        Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Accent
                                    });
                                }
                            }





                            if (boolvarcheck == "true")
                            {
                                card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveContainer()
                                {


                                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                {




                                                      new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                                                        {
                                                            Type = "ColumnSet",
                                                            Height = AdaptiveHeight.Auto,
                                                            Columns=new List<AdaptiveColumn> ()
                                                            {
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="200px",

                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {

                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text=luiscalenderentity,//+" Conference Hall",
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color=AdaptiveTextColor.Good
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              }  ,
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="150px",
                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {
                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text=datevar.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),//DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"),
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Good

                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              },

                                                             }
                                                      },

                                                      new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                                                        {
                                                            Type = "ColumnSet",
                                                            Height = AdaptiveHeight.Auto,
                                                            Columns=new List<AdaptiveColumn> ()
                                                            {
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="200px",

                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {

                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text="Name",
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color=AdaptiveTextColor.Good
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              }  ,
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="80px",
                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {
                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text="Start Time",
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Good

                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              },
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="80px",
                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {
                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text="End Time",
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color = AdaptiveTextColor.Good

                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              },

                                                             }
                                                      },




                                                    new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                                                    {
                                                        Type = "ColumnSet",
                                                        Height = AdaptiveHeight.Auto,

                                                        Columns=new List<AdaptiveColumn> ()
                                                        {


                                                          new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                          {
                                                              Type="Column",
                                                              Width="200px",
                                                              Items=Eventschedulesubject,


                                                          },

                                                           new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="80px",
                                                                 Items= Eventschedulestart,
                                                              },

                                                             new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                          {
                                                              Type="Column",
                                                              Width="80px",
                                                             Items= Eventscheduleend,
                                                          }



                                                        }


                                                    },
                                                }
                                });
                            }

                            else
                            {
                                card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveContainer()
                                {


                                    Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                {




                                                      new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                                                        {
                                                            Type = "ColumnSet",
                                                            Height = AdaptiveHeight.Auto,
                                                            Columns=new List<AdaptiveColumn> ()
                                                            {
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="500px",

                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {

                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text=" No scheduling for "+luiscalenderentity+" hall",
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color=AdaptiveTextColor.Good
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              }


                                                             }
                                                      },








                                                }
                                });
                            }


                        }

                        else
                        {
                            card.Body.Add(new AdaptiveContainer()
                            {


                                Items = new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                {




                                                      new AdaptiveColumnSet()
                                                        {
                                                            Type = "ColumnSet",
                                                            Height = AdaptiveHeight.Auto,
                                                            Columns=new List<AdaptiveColumn> ()
                                                            {
                                                              new AdaptiveColumn()
                                                              {
                                                                  Type="Column",
                                                                  Width="500px",

                                                                  Items=new List<AdaptiveElement>()
                                                                  {

                                                                      new AdaptiveTextBlock()
                                                                      {
                                                                          Type="TextBlock",
                                                                          Text=" No scheduling for "+luiscalenderentity+" hall",
                                                                           Weight=AdaptiveTextWeight.Bolder,
                                                                           Color=AdaptiveTextColor.Good
                                                                      }
                                                                  }
                                                              }


                                                             }
                                                      },








                                                }
                            });
                        }


                        var attachment1 = new Microsoft.Bot.Schema.Attachment
                        {
                            ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType,
                            Content = card,
                        };
                        var reply1 = MessageFactory.Attachment(attachment1);
                        await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply1, cancellationToken);



                    }
```